# Is there a CentOS server edition and a seperate desktop edition?

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, unix

Until now I have been using Ubuntu server. Ubuntu has separate downloads for desktop and server editions. I want to try a CentOS server, when I download a copy from a mirror through centos.org the ISO I get installs with a GUI.

On every download mirror, there is no distinguishing label on the downloads. So is there only one version of CentOS or separate versions for Desktop and Server?

I want a bare bones install with no GUI for a server, where can I download such a ISO?

Comment: It's possible ClearOS fits the bill for you?  It appears to be basically the same Redhat-ish distro but with a web frontend rather than a GUI.   A different approach to a server-distro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no separate installations for desktop and server since you can select the packages you want during the install. By default the 'minimal' install doesn't have Gnome (Or pretty much anything for that matter) but even with the full DVD downloads you can deselect the packages <s>(I believe it's called 'Graphical Desktop')</s>('GNOME Desktop Environment', you can install this from `yum` at a later time with `yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"`)

Generally my preferred method of CentOS/RedHat install is to use the 'NetInstall' ISO and point it to one of the HTTP mirrors, then you only download the packages you need. You can always `yum install` some later

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. To be honest I never did install centos, I just stopped install as soon as I saw the gui install screen show up.

Comment: @Joe "Read **all** the instructions before beginning this test…" :-)

Comment: @Joe RedHat/CentOS use an installer called 'Anaconda', which has both a text and graphical install mode. I can't remember the exact options but I think you can force text mode by typing `text<enter>` at the first boot screen

Answer (score 1):

There is only one version. During install you have the option of installing the GUI (KDE or GNOME) or no client-GUI-suite at all.